# Uninitialised constant issue in custom Rails namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails project and wanted to create some custom queries objects to be used by my application.

The class files are in `/app/queries/tasks`, an example of them looks like:

```
module Queries
  module Tasks
    class TaskQuery
      #some code
    end
  end
end
```

I have added the /app/queries path to the autoload constant, and verified it with `rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` and I can see that all the directories in /app/queries is included, including /app/queries/tasks.

However, when I try to consume the object like this (from the Rails console or from the controller):

```
Queries::Tasks::TaskQuery.new()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant Queries)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: My version is Rails 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual code would work if the queries folder contains a queries folder, which contains a tasks folder, which contains the task_query file:

```
queries
└── queries
    └── tasks
        └── task_query.rb
```

If the queries folder is in the `autoload_paths`, then isn't necessary you wrap `Tasks` within a `Queries` module, since `Queries` is the folder that's going to hold it. Use just `Tasks`:

```
module Tasks
  class TaskQuery
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I really do need it in a Queries namespace (there are other task namespaces and tasks in the project).  Any suggestions?

Comment: If so, then you can just use a folder structure like in the answer. It's going to be redundant for the queries case, but no for other app file types.